# Unable to add custom object on firebase node Android

Tags: android, object, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pojo

On just adding my Custom object it is finishing activity , not giving any error or indication , below is my code please help

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.create_profile_button:
            prepareData();
            if (CheckFields()) {
                mProgressDialog.show();
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(Boolean.FALSE);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Creating Profile");
                Toast.makeText(this, "All set to rock", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                throwData(createObject());
            }
            break;
    }
}

private School createObject() {

    School profile = new School();
    profile.setSchoolName(name);
    profile.setSchoolRegNo(regNo);
    profile.setSchoolBoard(board);
    profile.setSchoolCity(city);
    profile.setSchoolPincode(pincode);
    profile.setSchoolAddress(address);
    profile.setSchoolState(state);
    profile.setSchoolContact(contact);
    profile.setSchoolEmail(email);
    return profile;
}

private void throwData(School profile) {
    mDatabase.child(regNo).setValue(profile).addOnCompleteListener(CreateProfileActivity.this).addOnFailureListener(CreateProfileActivity.this);
}
```

School Class:

```
public class School {
    public School() {
    }

    public String SchoolRegNo,SchoolName, SchoolBoard,
            SchoolCity, SchoolPincode,
            SchoolAddress, SchoolState,
            SchoolContact, SchoolEmail;

    public String getSchoolRegNo() {
        return SchoolRegNo;
    }

    public void setSchoolRegNo(String schoolRegNo) {
        SchoolRegNo = schoolRegNo;
    }

    public String getSchoolName() {
        return SchoolName;
    }

    public void setSchoolName(String schoolName) {
        SchoolName = schoolName;
    }

    public String getSchoolBoard() {
        return SchoolBoard;
    }

    public void setSchoolBoard(String schoolBoard) {
        SchoolBoard = schoolBoard;
    }

    public String getSchoolCity() {
        return SchoolCity;
    }

    public void setSchoolCity(String schoolCity) {
        SchoolCity = schoolCity;
    }

    public String getSchoolPincode() {
        return SchoolPincode;
    }

    public void setSchoolPincode(String schoolPincode) {
        SchoolPincode = schoolPincode;
    }

    public String getSchoolAddress() {
        return SchoolAddress;
    }

    public void setSchoolAddress(String schoolAddress) {
        SchoolAddress = schoolAddress;
    }

    public String getSchoolState() {
        return SchoolState;
    }

    public void setSchoolState(String schoolState) {
        SchoolState = schoolState;
    }

    public String getSchoolContact() {
        return SchoolContact;
    }

    public void setSchoolContact(String schoolContact) {
        SchoolContact = schoolContact;
    }

    public String getSchoolEmail() {
        return SchoolEmail;
    }

    public void setSchoolEmail(String schoolEmail) {
        SchoolEmail = schoolEmail;
    }
}
```

Comment: is your `onCompleteListener` or `onFailedListener` get called?

Comment: And did you set any validation into your Firebase Database? (from Firebase Console)

Comment: No activity is starting again without error , it just it is only giving error when i am tring send my custom object ,and no validation used , if i am sending string as a value it is acceptable and giving me call back in on complete listner

Comment: where did `name`, `regNo`, `board`, etc that you write inside `createObject()` coming from?

Comment: from edit text , i am retriving

Comment: Did you check those value is not null? And another wild guess, maybe change `public String SchoolRegNo,SchoolName, SchoolBoard,` into one separate line for each data, like `public String SchoolRegNo;` and `public String SchoolName`, .. so on